# When running the query in Sqlite, I get the answer as 9.9. But that is not the correct answer

Tags: sql, sqlite, coursera-api

[https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-sample-database/]

I wrote this code to get the answer to 'What is the total price for the album “Big Ones”?'

```
SELECT  al.Title, i.Total, tr.albumid, SUM(tr.UnitPrice)
FROM ((((artists ar INNER JOIN albums al ON ar.ArtistId = al.ArtistId)
INNER JOIN tracks tr ON al.AlbumId = tr.AlbumId)
INNER JOIN invoice_items ii ON tr.TrackId = ii.TrackId)
INNER JOIN invoices i ON ii.invoiceid = i.invoiceid)
WHERE al.Title = 'Big Ones'
```

I got the `SUM(tr.UnitPrice)` as `9.9`.

But 9.9 is wrong. What should be the correct answer?

Tables from Chinook database is used. The link is provided above.

Comment: Shouldn't there be some `GROUP BY`s in that query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must sum the unit prices of all the tracks of the album, so only 2 tables are needed: `albums` and `tracks`.
Join them, and aggregate:

```
select a.title, 
       sum(t.unitprice) total_price
from albums a inner join tracks t 
on t.albumid = a.albumid
where a.title = 'Big Ones'
group by a.title
```

You can get the same result even if you omit the `group by` clause.

Answer (score 0):

I selected all the keys that matter and then joined the two tables. You have to sum the unit price for only "Big Ones"

**select** al.albumid, **sum**(tr.unitprice), al.title

**from** albums al

**inner join** tracks tr **on** al.albumid = tr.albumid

**where** al.title = "Big Ones"

Comment: Please use the editor to format the query as code (don't use bold)

Answer (score -1):

```
select
Title,
sum(UnitPrice)
from       albums
join       tracks
on         albums.AlbumId = tracks.AlbumId
where      albums.Title = 'Big Ones'
```